# Sequalize: Using order and limit together when eager loading associations

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a transaction table with multiple columns that correspond to primary keys in master tables. Basically simple one to one relations.

I am using limit to page through what may be a zillion transactions. When used with order and eager loading all the relations in the findAll function, the resulting query generates a subquery for the FROM clause which is used by the LIMIT. The ORDER on the other hand is applied to the outer query.

This does not provide the desired result as the order is not applied on the entire data set but rather on the set that is returned by the subquery.

Is there a way I can apply the order on the subquery instead.

I am using Sequelize 1.7.9

```
db.Transaction.findAll({
          order: '`transactions`.`some_date` DESC',
          limit: 10,
          offset: 10,
          include: [{
            model: db.Master1,
            attributes:['name'],
            include: [{
              model: db.Master2,
              attributes:['name']
            }]
          }, {
            model: db.Master3,
            include: [{
              model: db.Master4,
              attributes: ['name']
            }]
          }, {
            model: db.Master5,
            attributes: ['name'],
            where: {
              id: '12345'
            }
          }]          
        })
```

yields SQL of the form

```
SELECT `transactions`.*,
       `master1`.`name` AS `master1.name`,
       `master1.master2`.`name` AS `master1.master2.name`,
       `master3`.`name` AS `master3.name`,
       `master3.master4`.`name` AS `master3.master4.name`       
FROM
  (SELECT `transactions`.*,
          `master5`.`id` AS `master5.id`
   FROM `transactions`
   INNER JOIN `master5` AS `master5` ON `master5`.`id` = `transactions`.`session_id`
   AND `master5`.`id`='12345' LIMIT 10, 10) AS `transactions`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master1s` AS `master1` ON `master1`.`id` = `transactions`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master2s` AS `master1.master2` ON `master1.master2`.`id` = `master1`.`id_fk`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master3s` AS `master3` ON `master3`.`id` = `transactions`.`master3_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master4s` AS `master3.master4` ON `master3.master4`.`id` = `master3`.`master4_id`
ORDER BY `transactions`.`some_date` DESC;
```

Can the order be somehow shifted into the subquery?

```
SELECT `transactions`.*,
       `master1`.`name` AS `master1.name`,
       `master1.master2`.`name` AS `master1.master2.name`,
       `master3`.`name` AS `master3.name`,
       `master3.master4`.`name` AS `master3.master4.name`       
FROM
  (SELECT `transactions`.*,
          `master5`.`id` AS `master5.id`
   FROM `transactions`
   INNER JOIN `master5` AS `master5` ON `master5`.`id` = `transactions`.`session_id`
   AND `master5`.`id`='12345'  
   ORDER BY `transactions`.`some_date` DESC 
   LIMIT 10, 10) AS `transactions`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master1s` AS `master1` ON `master1`.`id` = `transactions`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master2s` AS `master1.master2` ON `master1.master2`.`id` = `master1`.`id_fk`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master3s` AS `master3` ON `master3`.`id` = `transactions`.`master3_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `master4s` AS `master3.master4` ON `master3.master4`.`id` = `master3`.`master4_id`;
```

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: June 2018, any solution?